# AWS Glue ETL scripts generation and portability

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

AWS Glue creates ETL scripts to transform, flatten, and enrich the data. The code is generated in Scala or Python and written for Apache Spark.

My question relates to these scripts portability. Can I use the same scripts(generated by AWS Glue) for Apache Spark on the other(non-AWS/EMR) Apache Spark clusters without modification or these scripts are tightly coupled with AWS Glue Apache Spark implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generated scripts both in Scala and Python depend on GlueContext and other Glue lib objects. 
AFAIK Glue run environment is not available outside of Glue.

I think a sensible approach is to use Glue as an abstraction over the hardware you execute Spark on, and write your scripts independent of Glue (in the end GlueContext and DynamicFrame does not provide so much functionality). Then you can run your code wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please point me to the documentation which describes how Glue can be used in such way(abstraction over the hardware for own Spark cluster)?

Comment: I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but Glue is built on top of EMR. When you run a job, an EMR cluster of a specified size is started for you. If you just want to use plain Spark, Glue is more convenient then EMR as whole hardware I abstracted away from you. Maybe I don't not use proper wording, but that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

We use two files per glue job : job_glue.py and job_pyspark.py.
Keep glue specific code in job_glue.py and non-glue code in job_pyspark.py.
This not only helps to run same code in Glue and EMR but also allows to do unit testing pyspark code as Glue mocks are not available currently. Test driven approach is much faster and cost effective compare to using dev endpoint and zeppelin notebook

Comment: How to you call//configure them - do you call /run the  job_glue.py and how does it call job_pyspark.py